# Why program in the background dies after logging out?

Tags: python, terminal, stderr

I have a simple python program that writes to stderr like this::

```
import sys
import time
while 1:
    time.sleep(10)
    sys.stderr.write('.')
```

When I run this in the background and then log out from bash, it seems it dies for the first write to stderr.

```
$ python err.py  &
[1] 25546
$ ..logout
```

huponexit is off and I can confirm form another terminal that the program is alive for a while after logging out.

My question is "why does it just exit after writing to stderr?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stderr` was initially connected to the terminal. After you logout, the OS revokes your access to that terminal (this is part of Unix *session management*), and attempting to write to it results in a `SIGHUP` signal being sent to the process, and the default action of this is to kill the process.

If you redirect `stderr` to a file, it should continue running.

Comment: A good explanation. There is a utility called "nohup" (part of GNU coreutils and some shells), which is intended for cases where you want to keep a program running after logging out.

Comment: He said that `huponexit` is off. If he's already done that, he doesn't need to use `nohup`, just redirect output away from the terminal.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar for your clear explanation. It really cleared my head.